# Character limit on a url

Tags: cakephp, substr

Still new to cakePHP but im trying to character limit a echo.

```
<h5 class="review_title"><?php echo $html->link($review(substr['Review']['title']0,50),$review['Review']['viewUrl']);?></h5>
```

Trying to limit this header to 50 Characters. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Wonderful.. -1, yet no feedback to help...

Comment: Your code has an obvious syntax error. Is that really your actual code?

Comment: Its what I have tried so far. Im trying to limit how many words/characters are being echo'ed. Again, im new to cakePHP/PHP,

Comment: I suggest you take a step back and read a basic PHP tutorial; specifically, look up how functions and arrays work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Juhana after reading the array tutorial, i figured out what I did wrong... That was not reading through the entire project. Appreciated.

```
<?php 
    $reviewed = substr($review['Review']['title'], 0, 20);?> 
    <h5 class="review_title"><?php echo $html->link($reviewed,$review['Review']['viewUrl']);?></h5>
```